# Visual Tracking of Executing WF Workflows

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

My workflows are hosted within a windows service. I like to know how to visually track the execution of these workflows. The Visual UI should update when the workflow has moved from one state to another, I have looked at the sample provided by [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624139.aspx) which visualize the workflow that it is actually executing which is not what I am looking for. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to roll your own. I've had some success reading from the AppFabric tracking database and producing a display using Graphviz (http://graphviz.org).

There's some information here on trying to use the WF designer to visualise a remote workflow - basically trying to rehydrate the Activity objects. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/06/08/wf4-visual-workflow-tracking-and-workflowinspectionservices.aspx